# How to model concrete table relationship where a child entity can contain different data, where the data belongs to the same generic type?

Tags: design-patterns, database-design, entity-relationship, data-modeling, concrete-inheritance

I am thinking of using [Concrete Table Inheritance](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html) for a use case, and need help determining if I need to use identifying vs non-identifying relationship, and also if how to structure my tables exactly.

**My use case**

I have an HTML form object where the form is the same mostly for many things, i.e. it is a large form that is identical for different products, except for `product_options`, which are different depending on exact `product_type`.  I want to save form data into tables, for storage/retrieval.  I think I want to use Concrete Table implementation, and need feedback on if that's the way to do it.

Here is what I am thinking:

[image]

Say if I want to retrieve information for product of type "A", I

1. Read selection_for, retrieve `product_type`
2. Based on `product_type` I read the appropriate options table

This seems to be a bit complicated...

I am also using Doctrine ORM to drive the database behind the scenes, so such data manipulation may prove to be difficult to implement via ORM API, but I wanted to consider this option first.

**Questions:**

- Will my design work as-is?  Can it be improved upon?  Did I implement Concrete Table design correctly?
- Do I use identifying or non-identifying relationship for the product option tables?

I can also do an alternative diagram like so:

[image]

and if one of those foreign keys is not NULL, then I read that key and then read the appropriate table to retrieve the data.

**Questions:**

Are any pros or cons to this second methods compared to the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Doctrine ORM has this handled.  3 different ways:

**Mapped Superclass**

Creates 3 tables in my case, each has both shared and concrete fields/columns

**Single Table Inheritance**

Puts all options into a single table (one table, no other tables are used).  Uses a `discriminator` field to pull the correct options.

**Class Table Inheritance**

aka `JOINED` type.  Creates 4 tables in my case, one for each type, plus main.  Options tables contain only the options relevant to them, and main table contains any shared fields, and the `discriminator` field.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

I guess just what I was looking for.  This takes SQL work out of my hands.

Now, to make the decision on which one to use ....